# What is needed to develop cross browser app using PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

I'm a bit confused as to what is needed in order to develop a PhoneGap app that is cross browser.

From their [Getting started](http://phonegap.com/start) page, I must select a platform. I thought this was cross platform.

Do I still have to download all packages for all phones if I truly want this to be cross platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two components to a PhoneGap application:

- The HTML/JavaScript application that (should) comprise the bulk of your code base.
- The platform-specific wrapper for each phone platform you want to support, with any custom native plugins you built.

If you can finish your entire app in HTML/JavaScript, with no custom plugins, you can use the [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) service to upload a zip file of your webapp and receive platform-specific packages for each platform you want to support, built in the cloud.

If you don't want to use cloud build, or need to develop your own custom plugins, you'll need the native SDK for each platform you want to support. At the very least, you need these to build the per-platform package to distribute to the app store.

You also need the native SDK for on-device debugging during development. If it's just HTML and JavaScript, testing on Chrome and IE9 can get you most of the way there, but you'll need on-device testing at some point.

Comment: Thanks. The company I'm using, is using Eclipse to develop my app. So I'm not sure what more I need than the PhoneGap Build and Eclipse. They have been a bit vague so far....

Comment: It's basically just HTML, CSS and JavaScript. If that's not 99% of your source code, then either you have very specific requirements that require native plugins, or you're doing it wrong. Eclipse should be fine for development and will enable you to do on-device testing for Android and BlackBerry. Testing on an iOS device requires XCode and testing on a Windows Phone requires Visual Studio. I'm unfamiliar with Bada and WebOS.

Comment: Yes, most is HTML/CSS/JS. Thanks for your feedback :)